# Android studio run configuration asks to select Android SDK although SDK is configured

Tags: android, android-studio, java-8, android-sdk-manager

Android studio (3.1.3) run configuration asks to select Android SDK although SDK is configured. Trying to re-sync causes the studio to "lose" the configuration of both the Android SDK, and the JDK. Re-installing the IDE didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should uninstall the SDK you already have installed (if you can delete the folders yourself better) and also uninstall android studio. Once this is done, reinstall android studio and let the installation wizard automatically install the SDK.

If this does not work, try selecting the android studio menu option Invalidate Caches / Restart.